# Term query does not return any results

Tags: elasticsearch, term-query

I am trying to find some entities in Elastic search using nested term query. If I execute my search query there are no hits. But if I change the query to use "match" instead of "term" I will have hits. What could I be doing wrong ?

What I am trying to achieve is to have only exact matches returned.

Entity in ES is as follows

```
"vehiclesCollection": [
    {
        "id": "c0163692-69c5-442e-a30c-a3789384904d",
        "additionalFields": {
            "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-    348f3e6a5485@1a61281d-73b0-41ea-964d-d869a172752d": "HaveNoIdea",
            "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@91b5e07e-6e09-4a81-a3ef-d43f1ea99b34": "Strane",
            "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@4fc4d50b-5c81-47f7-8c7a-7802c28c0dca": true,
            "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@c35b1e06-f918-4f70-a323-804c004ddcbe": "License Plate"
        },
        "searchableAdditionalFieldValues": [
            "License Plate",
            "Strane",
            "HaveNoIdea"
        ]
    }
]
```

HINT: This is just the part I perform the search on.

It has following mappings

```
{
  "vehiclesCollection": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "additionalFields": {
        "properties": {
          "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@1a61281d-73b0-41ea-964d-d869a172752d": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@4fc4d50b-5c81-47f7-8c7a-7802c28c0dca": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@91b5e07e-6e09-4a81-a3ef-d43f1ea99b34": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@c35b1e06-f918-4f70-a323-804c004ddcbe": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "searchableAdditionalFieldValues": {
        "type": "text",
        "index_options": "offsets",
        "analyzer": "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And search query (in which if term is switched with match it will work, but I want only exact matches)

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "vehiclesCollection.additionalFields.23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@c35b1e06-f918-4f70-a323-804c004ddcbe": {
                "value": "License Plate",
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "vehiclesCollection",
          "ignore_unmapped": false,
          "score_mode": "avg",
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "vehiclesCollection.additionalFields.23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@1a61281d-73b0-41ea-964d-d869a172752d": {
                "value": "HaveNoIdea",
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "vehiclesCollection",
          "ignore_unmapped": false,
          "score_mode": "avg",
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "vehiclesCollection.additionalFields.23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@4fc4d50b-5c81-47f7-8c7a-7802c28c0dca": {
                "value": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "vehiclesCollection",
          "ignore_unmapped": false,
          "score_mode": "avg",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My first idea is that its related to the search analyses. But I am not sure how to set them for this specific query. I am using Elasticsearch Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that you need to

- run your `term` queries on the `.keyword` sub-fields
- run your match queries on the `text` top-level fields

So your query would be (the first two nested `term` queries are using the `***.keyword` sub-field):

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "vehiclesCollection.additionalFields.23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@c35b1e06-f918-4f70-a323-804c004ddcbe.keyword": {
                "value": "License Plate",
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "vehiclesCollection",
          "ignore_unmapped": false,
          "score_mode": "avg",
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "vehiclesCollection.additionalFields.23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@1a61281d-73b0-41ea-964d-d869a172752d.keyword": {
                "value": "HaveNoIdea",
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "vehiclesCollection",
          "ignore_unmapped": false,
          "score_mode": "avg",
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "vehiclesCollection.additionalFields.23698e0d-e5ba-4c0e-9c41-09db40708f09@11b75c17-1f62-4a45-847b-348f3e6a5485@4fc4d50b-5c81-47f7-8c7a-7802c28c0dca": {
                "value": true,
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "vehiclesCollection",
          "ignore_unmapped": false,
          "score_mode": "avg",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this was the solution for it. So if I get it correctly you cant run term query and use fieldName.keyword if the value is boolean ?

Comment: I haven't touched the term query on the boolean field, that one was correct. The first two were not, because you were running a term query on a text (analyzed) field. term queries are best suited for "exact matches". So if you're searching for "License Plate" to match exactly, you need to use a term query on a keyword field.